# #officewriter note section is not getting copied while coping slides

Tags: officewriter

I am using below code to add a slide in PPT file at run time:

```
Presentation pres = ppta.Open(@"C:\Users\prabhat.kumar.yadav\Desktop\PPT\ParentPlan.pptx");
DataPrepration dataObject = new DataPrepration();//Populating Data
int noOfChildSlids = 19;//No of slide we need to add           
int sildeInsertPosition = 22;//position where we need to insert child slide
int NoOfChilds = 2;
for (int j = 0; j < NoOfChilds - 1; j++)
{
    int sildeCopyPosition = 3;//POstion from where we need to start copy slide
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfChildSlids; i++)
    {
        Slide slideToCopy = pres.Slides[sildeCopyPosition++];
        pres.Slides.CopySlide(slideToCopy, (sildeInsertPosition++));
    }
}
```

But the section is not getting copied in the slide added at run time.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in SoftArtisan's PowerPointWriter. This was fixed in version 10.1.2.350 of PowerPointWriter. This fix allows the notes of a slide to be copied when copying a slide.